# How to understand this CSS Menu Demo?

Tags: html, css

```css
      body {
        font-family: verdana;
      }

      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden; /*1.Why after deleting this line the menu diappear？*/
        background-color: #666;
      }

      ul li {
        float: left; /*2.Why after deleting the menu become a column shape？*/
      }

      ul li a {
        display: inline-block; /*3.Why after deleting the menu become smaller？*/
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
      }

      ul li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
  <body>
    <h2>Menu Demo 2:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="...">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am a newbie in CSS. This is just a very simple menu demo, but I thought for 3 hours and still didn't understand it. **I have put my 3 questions in the code**, that is:-

[1] Why did I delete that line 'overflow: hidden;' in 'ul' tag and then the menu just disappear?

[2] Why after deleting the line 'float: left;' in 'li' tage then the whole menu become a column shape？I think below that line I set 'a' tag as 'display:- inline-block'...... And what is the use for 'float: left' here?

[3] Why did I change 'display: inline-block' to 'display: inline', and then the whole menu become smaller and padding-top & padding-bottom for every 'a' tag doesn't work?

Comment: Questions asking us to, basically, find a tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: thanks but i just cannot understand that 3 lines...

Comment: Then I suggest you take the time do more research. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `overflow: hidden` contains the floated `li`s inside the `ul` by creating a blocking context, there is a in-depth explanation here:

[Adding CSS border changes positioning in HTML5 webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661264/adding-css-border-changes-positioning-in-html5-webpage)

The `float: left` pulls everything over to the left hand side, and in your case in a line, without a `float: left` or `right` the default is `none` which means elements will just stack which is why you're getting a column style layout.

The `inline-block`, or a `block` in other uses, makes the element incorporate the padding, in the example you provided, into its height. For example, if you had text 10px high and 20px padding on the top and bottom, the element would be 10px as the padding would get ignored, with adding a display type of `block` or `inline-block` this takes it into account and renders at a height of 50px.

Comment: thanks very much for your explanation! i just start to learn CSS and now I know I should not ask questions like this one here. I really should learn a lot and then come..