# What is the sense of using padding-top=padding-bottom="0.01em" assigned to class "w3-container" of w3.css?

Tags: padding, w3.css

The w3.css-class "w3-container" sets padding-top and padding-bottom to the value "0.01em".
The effect is different from using "0" instead.
What is the intention of this course of action?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this as workaround for issues of ["Collapsing margins"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

> "... In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might
>   or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin. ..."

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661264/adding-css-border-changes-positioning-in-html5-webpage),

Problem (extract):

> "... I expected the containing header element (grey) to appear at the
>   top of the screen, but it seems to take the margin from the inner div
>   (red). However if I add a border to the header it appears where I
>   expect and the red inner div only moves slightly! ..."

One anwser (extract)

> "...They can be overcome by adding padding to the parent element (in
>   this case, the `<header>`)... Notice the padding:0.001em;. This makes
>   the margins no longer collapse, but doesn't add any space to the
>   `<header>`. ..."

Well, just guessing.
Saludos,

Comment: Now, as you wrote it, I remember … I think you may guess right! ;) Thank you!